# Update table when checkbox is checked or unchecked

Tags: php, sql-update

I have a checkbox and need to update the table if it is checked

```
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        // Update the account
        $password = !empty($_POST['password']) ? password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT) : $account['password'];
        $stmt = $con->prepare('UPDATE `accounts` SET `live` = ? WHERE `id` = ?');
        $stmt->bind_param('si', $_POST['live'], $_GET['id']);
        $stmt->execute();
        header('Location: accounts.php?success_msg=2');
        exit;
    }
}

<form action="" method="post">
     <label for="live"> Live?</label>
     <input type="checkbox" name="live" id="live" <?php if (isset($_POST['live'])) { ?> value="1" <?php } else { ?> value="0" <?php } ?>>
</form>
```

I don't know why this code not working. I have enabled error logs but they don't show anything. `if` statement redirects me through header